Microsoft Graph api code skipping unexpectedly
First of all let me explain my environment, which is I have

Visual Studio 2022
Microsoft.Graph version 5.56.0.0
Microsoft.Identity.Client version 4.63.0.0

I am using this code where after line
var mailFolderCollectionPage = await  graphClient.Me.MailFolders.GetAsync();

Visual Studio debugger is completely skipping the exiting application.
Here is my C# code - is there anything wrong with this code?
I have got these permissions in Azure

Code:
private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ReadMailsFromExchangeServerByusingmsGraph()
{
    var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient();

    // Fetch mail folders asynchronously
    var mailFolderCollectionPage = await  graphClient.Me.MailFolders.GetAsync();

    // Now you can iterate over the MailFolders
    foreach (var mailFolder in mailFolderCollectionPage.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mailFolder.DisplayName);
    }
}

private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient()
{
    var tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"];

    // Value from app registration
    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"];
    var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"];

    // The client credentials flow requires that you request the
    // /.default scope, and pre-configure your permissions on the
    // app registration in Azure. An administrator must grant consent
    // to those permissions beforehand.

    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    // using Azure.Identity;
    var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
       {
           AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
       };

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    return graphClient;
}


I don't know what you mean by "completely skipping the exiting application".

Do you await the call of your method? Also you only get a list of folder names, not their items.

I see that you are calling Me endpoint and making use of ClientSecretCredential grant type which is not supported. You need to call var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].MailFolders.GetAsync(); while using ClientSecretCredential.

Do you want to read mail folders of any user or of any signed-in user? You have granted delegated permission User.Read, but you authenticate with client secret which works only with application permissions. Could you explain what is the goal? You don't catch any exception.

If you still want to call await graphClient.Me.MailFolders.GetAsync(); then switch to user interactive flows with delegated API permissions

@user2250152 our application is a console application and it will run in background

@Rukmini our application is a console application and it will run in background


Note that: /me endpoint works only with user interactive flow not with ClientSecretCredential flow.


Hence either grant application type API permissions and use ClientSecretCredential flow.
If you want to call /me endpoint then grant delegated API permissions and use any user interactive flow to perform the action.

As you want to get the Mail folders, you need to grant Mail.Read application type API permission:

And call await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].MailFolders.GetAsync() and modify the code:
namespace ReadMailsFromExchange
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await ReadMailsFromExchangeServerByUsingMSGraph();
        }

        private static async Task ReadMailsFromExchangeServerByUsingMSGraph()
        {
            var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient();

            var mailFolderCollectionPage = await graphClient.Users["UserID"].MailFolders.GetAsync();

            foreach (var mailFolder in mailFolderCollectionPage.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mailFolder.DisplayName);
            }
        }

        private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient()
        {
            var tenantId = "TenantID";
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            return graphClient;
        }
    }
}



what is UserID here i mean in line await graphClient.Users["UserID"].MailFolders.GetAsync();

The object ID of the user

,in our mail i can see it as "a1f4a71e-7de1-472c-bd11-d1c8ae3eddf6" given by the azure team.Is this correct?

Yes try with this

i think async on main method cause issues static async Task Main(string[] args)

In the code you are using just change the line var mailFolderCollectionPage = await  graphClient.Me.MailFolders.GetAsync(); to var mailFolderCollectionPage = await graphClient.Users["UserID"].MailFolders.GetAsync();

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@peter Any update?
