The code for Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices version 2.2.1.0 is not working, even though the token is being generated
I have a development environment as below

Visual Studio 2022 .net version 4.8
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices version 2.2.1.0
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth version 15.0.0.0
Microsoft.Identity.Client version 4.63.0.0
and also I have Azure permission as below


I have written code below that generates a Token, but when it reaches the line
var folders = _service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(10));

It throws error like Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 'The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'
Below is the full code
private static void ReadMailsFromExchangeServer()
{
    //  _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("test@test.com", "qwerty", "tng");
    try
    {

        string token = GetAccessToken();

        ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016)
        {
            Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
            Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(token),
        }; // Use your EWS endpoint


        // Impersonate the user you want to act on behalf of
        _service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "test@test.com");
        // Set X-AnchorMailbox header to the SMTP address of the mailbox being accessed
        _service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "test@test.com");//test@test.com
        _service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-PreferServerAffinity", "true");
        var folders = _service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(10));
        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(folder.DisplayName);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
        private static async void GetTokens()
        {
            // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0
            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"])
                .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"])
                .WithTenantId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"])
                .Build();

            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

            try
            {
                var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
                var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
                ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
                ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
                   new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "test@test.com");

                //Include x-anchormailbox header
                ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "test@test.com");


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }


The error is due to insufficient permission. You need to add outlook permission microsoft exchange api permission to the application to make it work

Select add permission -> APIs in my organisation -> Microsoft exchange - grant application api permission

@rukmini Is it required full_access_as_app or Mail.Read??

You can try with Mail.Read application type API permission and let me know if it works

And still you get the same error then  full_access_as_app also is required

@Rukmini there is a security issue our organization azure team saying, something like it will give access to all other mail boxes. Is that correct? any work around is there? i will update Mail.Read results soon and waiting the azure team to do that

Yes application permissions will give access to all mail boxes under the tenant

Workaround is you need to switch to delegated API permissions with user interactive flow to generate access token

@Rukmini our application is a console application i mean background application ,i believe app permission is required

Then yes, full_access_as_app app permission is required

Posted the answer please let me know if it works

@Rukmini the code in answer is same as i posted in question rite? only thing is you added full_access_as_app in azure configuration side as rite?and also Mail.Read works for you or full_access_as_app is required

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes and full_access_as_app is required

@Rukmini Is there any way full_access_as_app can be given to my application only

You cannot restrict application type API permissions as they are tenenat wide

@Rukmini not yet , we are waiting for the azure team update.Since we are big organization ,i dont know whether we will get full_access_as_app as it will affect the security .Any other alternate mechanism

AFAIK no alternative mechanism for application type permissions

Any update on the issue?

@Rukmini we are waiting the approval from security team for full_access_as_app for particular folder and our organization is big. So still waiting and will update you for sure and thanks

@Rukmini now are going with a different approach  like  instead of EWS we are going to use POP3 protocol to read mails as getting permission 'full_access_as_app' is difficult ..

@Rukmini Sure, I did it now. Thanks for your quick and prompt help. If any further assistance is required, I will ping you here

Any update on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78862601/microsoft-graph-api-code-skipping-unexpectedly

@Rukmini  what is UserID here i mean in line await graphClient.Users["UserID"].MailFolders.GetAsync();

Initially I got the same error when granted same permissions as you:

The error "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" usually occurs of the application do not have required permissions to perform the action.
Hence to resolve the error, you need to grant Office 365 Exchange Online full_access_as_app application type API permission to the Microsoft Entra ID application like below:

After granting the required API permission, I am able to fetch the folders successfully:
namespace EWSIntegration
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await ReadMailsFromExchangeServer();
        }

        private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ReadMailsFromExchangeServer()
        {
            try
            {
                string token = await GetAccessToken();

                ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016)
                {
                    Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
                    Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(token),
                };


                // Impersonate the user you want to act on behalf of
                _service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "test @test.com");
                // Set X-AnchorMailbox header to the SMTP address of the mailbox being accessed
                _service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "test @test.com");
                _service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-PreferServerAffinity", "true");
                var folders = _service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(10));
                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Folder: {folder.DisplayName}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

                private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            string clientId = "ClientID";
            string clientSecret = "ClientSecret"; 
            string tenantId = "TenantID"; 

            try
            {
                var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .Build();
                var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
                var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
                return authResult.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while acquiring the token: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}


